# BitmapFactory.decodeFile returning null on certain devices

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

I have been trying to capture an image and resize it (to display it) and store its base64 value.

```
private String setImageAndReturnBase64String(ImageView imageView) {

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 400, 400, false);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

    return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

Where `mCurrentPhotoPath` is

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
```

and `storageDir` is

```
File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    if (!(storageDir != null && storageDir.exists())) {
        if (storageDir != null) {
            storageDir.mkdir();
        }
    }
```

with all the necessary permissions and the file providers in the manifest.

But in certain devices `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);` returns null causing runtime exceptions.

Stack trace from FireBase:

```
android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3152)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2495)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1354)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5443)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:728)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:618)
arrow_drop_down
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.app.in/com.app.activities.JobCard}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults (ActivityThread.java:3720)
android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3107)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3152)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2495)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1354)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5443)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:728)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:618)
arrow_drop_down
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap (Bitmap.java:636))
android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult (Activity.java:6442)
android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults (ActivityThread.java:3716)
android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3107)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3152)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2495)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1354)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5443)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:728)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

**How do I prevent this run-time exception from happening on certain devices?**

**EDIT: After implementing the method suggested in the comments, this is what I've been facing.**

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.app.in/com.app.activities.Detailed}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=android:fragment:0, request=0, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.app.in/com.app.activities.Detailed}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3121)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3152)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2495)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1354)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5443)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:728)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:618)

Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=android:fragment:0, request=0, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.app.in/com.app.activities.Detailed}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults (ActivityThread.java:3720)
android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3107)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3152)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2495)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1354)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5443)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:728)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:618)

Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
com.app.fragments.ModeDetailsFragment.setImageAndReturnBase64String (ModeDetailsFragment.java:224)
com.app.fragments.ModeDetailsFragment.onActivityResult (ModeDetailsFragment.java:198)
android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult (Activity.java:6466)
android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults (ActivityThread.java:3716)
android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3107)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3152)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2495)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1354)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5443)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:728)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

**Modified Method**

```
private String setImageAndReturnBase64String(ImageView imageView) {

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    if(bitmap == null) {
        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, options);
        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, 400, 400);
        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, options);
    } else {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 400, 400, false);
    }
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

    return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
}

private int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Comment: My guess is that you are running out of heap space. Rather than read in the full image, then scale it down, use `BitmapFactory.Options` and `inSampleSize` to read in a scaled-down image, and use less memory.

Comment: VM free: 7.21MB
VM total: 19.58MB
VM max: 96MB
Battery level: 71%
Manufacturer: LGE
Model: LG-K420
Board: Msm8916
Android API: 22
Android OS: 5.1.1
Brand: Lge
RAM: 1.86GB

This is the device data during the crash.

Comment: @CommonsWare Could you please look into the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` will return `null` if the `Bitmap` would become too big for available memory. You can read this 'feature' every week on this site.

Just try with a smaller image.